# How to correctly import a module dynamically and use a function from it?

Tags: node.js, import, commonjs, node.js-got

I am importing `got` dynamically, like this:

```
  const { default: moduleGot } = await import('got');
  moduleGot();
```

Then, I want to execute a function from it:

```
const response = await got(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`,
    "Authorization": `Bearer ${config.pinata.jwt}`
  },
  body: data
})
```

But I am getting `ReferenceError: got is not defined`

What is the right way of importing it and then use `got`?

Comment: Have you looked at the `got` documentation - there are basic usage examples (which can help solve your issue).

Comment: All the examples I found on their documentation use `import got from 'got'`. Where should I look at?